# Updating the price on changing the size

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to update the price displayed in span as soon as the `product.selected_size` is changed. In this case product is a computed property of my component.

```
<div class="prices-wrapper">
<span class="price-normal">&euro; {{ product.prices[product.selected_size] }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a new computed property.

```
computed: {
  price: function () {
    return this.product.prices[this.product.selected_size]
  }
}
```

and

```
<div class="prices-wrapper">
    <span class="price-normal">&euro; {{ price }}</span>
</div>
```